# getimagesize() returning null values

Tags: php, file-upload, getimagesize

I have a form in that i have file upload to upload an image. I need to get the image height and width. For this I’m using `getimagesize()` method though I passes the correct variable it was not returning any value.

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['tmp_name']);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];
```

But I’m getting the null values. I checked whether I’m passing correct data or not.. I got this url: `/private/temp/phpXrth`.
I dont where I’m making wrong. I googled it but they are giving the same solution. Could anyone help me for this?
If I print the $_FILES['artimage'];

```
Array (
[name] => 0694_a5bb.jpeg [type] => image/jpeg 
[tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/php5s9md9 
[error] => 0 
[size] => 13038 )
```

Comment: Are you sure `$size[0]` are null? That should mean `$size` is false, which hints that you have notices turned off in PHP, which means you are not seeing all the errors you have in your code.

Comment: Can you describe the answer you have given Im unable to get you

Comment: That’s not an answer but a comment about error handling in your code. It does not solve your problem, but should help with some other pieces of your code. If I had to guess, the image you’re passing can’t be used to calculate width and height (as per manual) or your file is something else than image. We can’t know, as you’re not telling whta you are trying to upload.

Comment: can you show me what your array `$_FILES` looks like

Comment: could you check it the edit part

Comment: please check my updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607740/getimagesize-returning-null-values/24608039#24608039 if this still does not work you need to share more code

Answer (score 0):

your code looks correct if temporary file exists of course

Try to make dump of $size value

> var_dump($size);

Is There any result ?

also pay attention to html uploading form

if There feature

> enctype="multipart/form-data">

like

> form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

?

Comment: check if GD library being installed with <?php phpinfo(); ?> !

Comment: also execute this code

<?php
var_dump(gd_info());
?>

Comment: do you see any result after it
 <?php var_dump(gd_info()); ?> 

?

Comment: yes its showing the Gd version, bundled compatible and etc

Comment: write here what data is returned after dump
<?php
var_dump(file_exists($_FILES['artimage']['name']), $size);
?>

Comment: you must use this
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['tmp']);

instead of
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['name']);

Comment: but there is no attribut ['tmp'] it has ['tmp_name']

Comment: try it

$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['tmp_name']);

Comment: yes tmp_name
I was mistaken I wrote from mind ))

try it
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['tmp_name']);

It must work 100000%

Comment: write here plz result of dump
after it
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['tmp_name']);
var_dump(file_exists($_FILES['artimage']['tmp_name']),$size);

Comment: also if it doesnt work then
move temporary file to your host location, maybe you haven’t permission 

<?php
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['artimage']['tmp_name']),$your_new_location_full_path_with_name_file_at_your_working_dir) {
$size = getimagesize($your_new_location_full_path_with_name_file_at_your_working_dir);
var_dump($size);
}
?>

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['artimage']['name']);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];

echo "width = ".$size['0'];
echo "<br>";
echo "height = ".$size['1'];
```

Comment: then something else is wrong, please share your html form code